# Rails. Creating a module with a class setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module (it's a standard module, not a Concern. Should it be a `Concern`? What makes it a `Concern`?) that looks like this:

```
module TreeNutrient
   def grow
      "grows #{number} inches"
   end
end
```

When I include it in a class, I want to be able to set inches like this:

```
class Tree
    include TreeNutrient
    set_number 5
    ...
end
```

or

```
class NotATree
    include TreeNutrient
    set_number 0
end
```

So that when I call `grow` on the respective plant, it grows by the set number of inches.

How do I do this? The `set_number` method has to be a class level method... not just a standard `attr_writer`.

**Updated**

I have this as a solution right now (I think this works?), not tested... but it feels dirty...

```
module TreeNutrient
  def self.set_number(number)
     @number = number
  end

  def self.number
     @number
  end

  def grow
     "grows #{self.class.number} inches"
  end
end
```

but I feel like I'm hacking around Ruby right now. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include ActiveSupport (you shouldn't for this, it's pretty heavy and this is simple) you could do a little meta programming. Concerns also come from ActiveSupport.

This is what I would do:

```
module TreeNutrient
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def set_number n
      define_method(:number) { n }
    end
  end
end


class Tree
  include TreeNutrient
  set_number 5

  def grow
    "grows #{number} inches"
  end
end

puts Tree.new.grow
# grows 5 inches
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `mattr_accessor`

http://apidock.com/rails/Module/mattr_accessor

From page:

```
module HairColors
  mattr_accessor :hair_colors
end

class Person
  include HairColors
end

Person.hair_colors = [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.hair_colors     # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.new.hair_colors # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
```

NOTE: Needs ActiveSupport/Rails to work

Comment: I don't have rails

Comment: @Jwan622 You can use `ActiveSupport` library or grab it from source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors.rb